Overload function with SupportsInt and not SupportsInt?
I want to overload the function below so if passed a value that supports int() Python type hints int otherwise Python type hints the value passed.
Python typing module provides a SupportsInt type we can use to check if our value supports int.
from typing import Any, SupportsInt, overload

@overload
def to_int(value: SupportsInt) -> int: ...

@overload
def to_int[T: NotSupportsInt???](value: T) -> T: ...

def to_int(value: Any) -> Any:
    try:
        return int(value)
    except TypeError:
        return value


But in our second overload statement how can we specify all values that don't support int?

Hi Matt,  Python's type hinting system doesn't provide a built-in way to directly express this concept. But you can achieve what you want by using a combination of type hints and generic types.

Types make positive promises - they specify things an object can do. Not things an object can't do.
If you have an object of static type float, you know this object supports __int__, so you know it's a member of type SupportsInt.
If you have an object of static type object, object does not have an __int__ method, but this object still might support __int__. The object could be a float, or an instance of some other subclass of object that supports __int__. You don't know whether passing it to to_int will return an int.
Your second overload is trying to say "Doesn't support __int__? Then return the original type." What it should say is "Don't know if it supports __int__? Then maybe return the original type, or maybe return int." You'd do that with an unbounded type variable and a union return type, like this:
from typing import overload, SupportsInt, TypeVar

T = TypeVar('T')

@overload
def to_int(value: SupportsInt) -> int: ...

@overload
def to_int(value: str) -> int: ...

@overload
def to_int(value: T) -> T | int: ...

def to_int(value):
    try:
        return int(value)
    except TypeError:
        return value

Note that I've also added a separate overload for str. str doesn't actually support __int__, so it doesn't fall under the SupportsInt overload - calls like int('35') are handled by a special case in int.__new__.
And sure, sometimes you'll have a case like to_int([]), where you know the specific concrete type of the object, and you know the int call will fail. But the type system doesn't propagate that information the way it would need to for more specific annotations to work. To the type checker, an instance of list might be an instance of some weird __int__-supporting list subclass, even if a human looking at the code can see it's not.

Sadly, Python's type annotation system currently does not have a good way to specify negative types. Here is what you can do:
from typing import Any, SupportsInt, TypeVar, Union, overload, cast

T = TypeVar('T')

# Option 1: downside: slight runtime penalty
def to_int_option_1(value: T) -> Union[int, T]:
    try:
        return int(cast(SupportsInt, value))
    except TypeError:
        return value

# Option 2: downside: ignoring type information, you'll need to make sure it's not hiding any bugs
def to_int_option_2(value: T) -> Union[int, T]:
    try:
        return int(value)  # type: ignore
    except TypeError:
        return value

This is a bit broader than the type you're looking for, but it'll probably have to do (considering overlapping signatures with incompatible return types as suggested by other answers aren't supported).
This may make using your function slightly inconvenient, as it doesn't tell you the return type based on if the argument is a SupportsInt or not. For example:
foo = to_int('37')
reveal_type(foo) # str | int, expected: int
bar = to_int([37])
reveal_type(bar) # list[int] | int, expected: list[int]

... which means you might have to insert things like assert isinstance(foo, int) or typing.cast(list[int], bar) to get type checking to work properly.

You can do better with an overload, if you write the overload correctly - overlapping signatures with compatible return types are okay. My answer's overloads pass type checking.

Yours might be better from a documentation point of view, but from a type checking point of view our solutions seem to be equivalent (as in, reveal_type(to_int('37')) prints str | int and reveal_type(to_int([37])) prints list[int] | int)

But reveal_type(to_int(3.5)) gives int for my version and int | float for yours.

I think you got mixed up because str doesn't actually support __int__ - the int constructor special-cases str. (Come to think of it, it might be a good idea to add a separate overload for that.)

Ah I didn't think of that, you're right. Your answer seems to be the closest to the behaviour Matt wants that is possible with the current mypy and python typing features.

You could implement like this:
Union to allow either SupportsInt or any other type.
Use a type variable T and Union to specify that the second overload can accept any type.
In the second overload, we specify that the return type can be either int or the same type as the input value.
This way, if a value supports int, it will be converted to int, otherwise, the value will be returned as is.

from typing import Any, SupportsInt, TypeVar, Union, overload

T = TypeVar('T')

@overload
def to_int(value: SupportsInt) -> int: ...

@overload
def to_int(value: T) -> T: ...

def to_int(value: Union[SupportsInt, T]) -> Union[int, T]:
    try:
        return int(value)
    except TypeError:
        return value





This fails type checking due to overlapping signatures with incompatible return types.
